# Prime Factor Program Always Returning 3

Tags: python-3.x

Diving into coding for the first time and I'm trying to tackle the third Project Euler problem (finding the largest prime factor of 600851475143) and I want to write a function that simply returns the prime factors before I determine the largest one.

I cobbled together some shoddily written Python code below. It finds the factor of any number just fine but for some reason, the prime factor function always returns 3. Is there something I'm missing? Here's the code:

```
def factorize(j):
    factors = []
    print("Finding factors...")
    for i in range(1, j+1):
        if j % i == 0:
            factors.append(i)
    print("Done!")
    print(factors)
    return factors

def prime(n):
    primes = []
    for factor in n:
        for p in range(1, factor+1):
            for i in range (2, p):
                if p % i == 0:
                    break
                else:
                    primes.append(p)
                print(primes)
                return primes

print("Number to factor: ")
num = int(input())
num = factorize(num)
print("Now to find the primes...")
prime(num)
```

Thanks again for your help!

Comment: If you know it is shoddy, why not address that first?

Comment: That was me being pre emptively self deprecating, really.

Answer (score 0):

You put a `return` statement deep inside the nested loops of `prime`, so *none* of those loops completes an iteration.